# International characters in HTML5 email input e.g. Ä, ä, Ö, ö, Ü, ü, ß

Tags: html, forms, validation, input, email-validation

I have found that a HTML5 form input of type `email` does not accept international characters such as Ä, ä, Ö, ö, Ü, ü, ß out of the box.

Having looked into the spec, I think I can override the default validation by adding the `pattern` attribute, but there is conflicting information as to whether or not this should be done.

e.g.
Against modifying:
https://html.com/attributes/input-pattern/
http://html5pattern.com/Emails

For modifying:
https://justmarkup.com/log/2015/02/input-type-email-better-dont-use-it/

My questions:

- Should I be "fixing" this or are there good reasons that browsers do not allow HTML5 email inputs to accept these characters?
- If modifying it is okay, is using the pattern attribute correct here? Is using Unicode for these characters in the regex correct?
- If modifying it is okay, am I fixing this problem in the correct manner? Are there other settings/attributes within my HTML that impact what the default validation rules are for email inputs?

This question is borne out of a customer trying to register on a website I'm working on, they have the ü in their email address e.g. test_ü_test@example.com and are unable to register.

Comment: More context and live example for anyone who wants to answer: https://jsfiddle.net/b9r5vk6y/